# regular expression in jquery to get image filename

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to extract filename with path and its extension separately from image's src with jquery.

for example:

```
<img src="images/cat/kitty.gif" id="myimg" />
```

I need to get "images/cat/kitty" and ".gif" from above code.

how can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method instead:

```
$('#image_id').attr('src');
```

If you want name and extension separately, you can do:

```
var arr = $('#image_id').attr('src').split('.');
alert(arr[0]);    // name
alert(arr[1]);    // extension
```

Answer (score 5):

To extract only the file name:

```
    var name = $('#myimg').attr("src");
    var parts = name.split('/');
    name = parts[parts.length-1];
```

Answer (score 4):

No regex needed. Use `.split()`:

```
var ret = $('#myimg').attr('src').split(/\./);

console.log(ret[0]);  // === 'images/cat/kitty'
console.log(ret[1]);  // === 'gif'
```

Comment: Amusingly=) You said no regex needed and then wrote example with regex

Comment: @Serjio: true story. But I guess I meant using `.split()` instead `.exec()` or `.match()`. I should replace that `.split()` argument with `'.'` tho :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a complex image path that uses multiple '.' such as -

http://website.com/app/folder/imagemanager.php../../../user_images/2982034/images/image.png

Although you could clean up the path beforehand, if not, using jQuery you could try -

```
// Get the source
var image_src = $(el).attr('src');

// Get the extension. As mentioned above, using split() and pop() 
var extension = image_src.split('.').pop();

// Get just the path. Replace the extension with ''
var path = image_src.replace('.'+extension,'');
```